# Can i do this in javascript ?(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckData(e) {

                var form = e.form;
                var dataItem = e.dataItem;

                var r = <%=Session["count"] %>;
                var s = [];
                var t = [];

                for (i=1;i<r;i++)
                {
                    s.push(<%=Session["level"+i] %>;

                }
                for(i=1;i<r;i++)
                {
                    t.push(<%=Session["level"+i+"val"] %>
                }

                if(e.mode="edit")
                {

                }
            }
    </script>
```

I try to combind session in to variable in JavaScript but my session has dynamic session this code get error when I try to build.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? I'm going to overlook the obvious, which is that your Javascript syntax is bad because you say you are getting a compile time error.

Comment: ASP runs on the server and spits out HTML and Javascript code, which is then run in the browser. The two are running in entirely different environments at different times. In short: no.

Comment: Give us the server-side information on those Session variables. You're calling them incorrectly, but I can't show you the right way unless I understand what you're storing in Session.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  Not unless you have a variable on the server named `i`.  You'll want to put that loop completely on the server.  Something like:

```
List<int> s = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    s.Add((int)Session["level" + i]);
}
```

Then in your client code:

```
var s = [<%= string.Join(",", s) %>];
```

Comment: "on the server" means session on server side Right !.

Comment: @user1710716 You're still confused. Code inside `<% %>` tags  runs on the server, but `i` is client-side code. You can't mix them like that, you're getting an error because your *server* does not recognize `i`. This answer provides a way to change you server-side code to make your JavaScript work as you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%
System.Text.StringBuilder sJscriptArray = new StringBuilder();
System.Text.StringBuilder sJscriptVals = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"]); i++)
{
    if (sJscriptArray.Length > 0)
    {
        sJscriptArray.Append(", ");
        sJscriptVals.Append(", ");
    }
    sJscriptArray.Append(Session[String.Concat("level", i)]);
    sJscriptVals.Append(Session[String.Concat("level", i, "val")]);

}
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckData(e) {
    var form = e.form;
    var dataItem = e.dataItem;

    var s = [ <%= sJscriptArray.ToString() %> ];
    var t = [ <%= sJscriptVals.ToString() %>];
    var r = s.length;

    if(e.mode="edit")
    {

    }
}
</script>
```